# Error with Line insertion

Tags: excel, vba

Still learning Excel, so apologies if this is a simple fix.

I am trying to insert 12 rows above the bottom row, copy a range from a separate worksheet, paste the range into the new rows, and then select the relative cell of C1 in the new rows as the active cell.

I have run into two issues here: the first being that it simply doesn't do anything, and the second being that it seems I can't use my last row function do do this. I used the Macro Recorder to get a baseline of what I wanted to do and then edited it to fit.

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell = LastRow .Cells("C".0)
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Rows("1:12").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:U2").Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.Offset(-12, 2) = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
With Sheet1 '<~~ Sheet where you want to insert
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Insert 12 blank rows above the last row
    For i = 1 To 12
        .Rows(LastRow).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i

    '~~> Copy and paste
    Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:U2").Copy .Range("C" & LastRow)
End With
```

Comment: That did it! I wish I was versed enough to understand how that works.

Comment: Didn't the comments help? :)

Comment: Yeah, I just meant understanding the language. I don't know VBA that well yet, so I don't know how each of those parts works together to make it work.